# Subdirectory Folder access with with Specific URL (post /subPage or sub.domain.com/)

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting

I have installed one wordpress website in `https://example.com`
And in Same Directory i have one folder `/subFolder` that i want to install one more project
with `https://example.com/subFolder`

How we rewrite the .htaccess file.